# neo4j round trip match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple query like so:

```
MATCH (u1:User {id: 1})-[:WANTS]->(:Card)<-[:HAS]-(u2:User)
WITH u1, u2
MATCH (u1)-[:HAS]->(:Card)<-[:WANTS]-(u2)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id)
```

Now user 1 has 500 users whom he is interested in, and among those 500, there are 150 who are interested in him. It's a bit weird since the query seems so simple but it's taking 22 seconds to perform it, all the fields needed to be indexed are indexed.

Here is my output:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id)
151
Returned 1 row in 22270 ms
```

Mind you when I do each of the query directions separately, they turn out to be fast:

```
MATCH (u1:User {id: 1})-[:WANTS]->(:Card)<-[:HAS]-(u2:User)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id)
// COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id)
// 556
// Returned 1 row in 220 ms

MATCH (u1:User {id: 1})-[:HAS]->(:Card)<-[:WANTS]-(u2:User)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id)
// COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id)
// 14351
// Returned 1 row in 375 ms
```

I just want to know if the query can be optimized because I'm pretty neo4j can do this with one hand tied behind its back.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.  See how this does:

```
MATCH (u1:User {id : 1})-[:HAS]->(c1:Card)
WITH u1, c1
MATCH (c1)<-[:WANTS]-(u2:User)
WHERE u1 <> u2
WITH u1, u2, c1
MATCH (u1)-[:WANTS]->(c2:Card)
WITH u1, u2, c1, c2
MATCH (c2)<-[:HAS]-(u2)
RETURN count(DISTINCT u2.id)
```

This query ran much faster in my tests.

Comment: Hey Jim, thanks for the input. The whole query takes 17 seconds to return the 151 nodes. I tried to take the query apart to see how long each match takes. Everything except the last `MATCH` only takes 300ms+. With the last match it goes up to 17 seconds. Any idea why?

Comment: Jim, I've updated the question with more info. I added results for each of the query directions and they seemed to be fast. There's something fishy going on but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: Is there any possibility that you have a case (like cybersam was suggesting below) where user 1 has a card that user 1 wants, so there there is a self-referential loop?

Comment: Looking at how your query is constructed, the first match returns 556 different u2 nodes. Apart from optimization, I think (I don't know for sure!) the second match will be performed 556 times, with 14351 unique sub-results for each match, with only 151 unique successes. I bet it's that second part that's killing you.

Comment: Yet another thought... how many cards are there? I wonder if it might be quicker to attack the problem 'sideways' through the card nodes?

Comment: gotcha, there are so far 14k distinct cards in the graph and grows very slowly through the years so yeah that's a good point to attack. what's your idea?

Comment: You rock Jim! I'm not sure what made it faster, was it the WHERE u1 <> u2?

Comment: It is the staged use of the card nodes. It keeps each individual subquery small.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the node labels to help limit the nodes that are evaluated. Does this query improve the performance?

```
MATCH (u1:User)-[:WANTS]->(:Card)<-[:HAS]-(u2:User)-[:WANTS]->(:Card)<-[:HAS]-u1
WHERE u1.id = 1 AND u1.id <> u2.id
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id)
```

Comment: Sorry this query took 82 seconds. `Returned 1 row in 82959 ms`